# ADF,Extract file from auto created folder

Tags: sql, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake

How do I extract a file from a folder which is created dynamically like f1/folder_1995/folder_12/folder_01/file.dat?

I have more than 10 years worth of files stored in data lake needed to be in DB using meta data but I'm having a hard time setting the path because it already existed I can't use with last modified.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, please vote up and  mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According my experience, we can not extract a file from a folder which is created dynamically(don't know the folder name).

We must know the full path of the file, at least the folder name to filter the files.